# Finding closest match between columns by unique index

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some assistance with a formula in excel. I am trying to iterate through a range of values in different columns given some unique index.

Thank you in advance for your kind support!

I have the following data:

Table 1 contains columns for GoodNumber (GN), Purchase Price, Reference Price.

```
GN | Purchase Price | Reference Price (?)    
E | 2,36 |    
C |4,25 |    
F | 9,3 |    
A   | 1,2   |    
B | 7,63    |    
D   |5,47   |
```

Table 2 contains a list of GoodNumbers with different Market Prices per GN (GN from Table 1 corresponds to GN from Table 2):

```
GN |    Market Prices    
A | 2,99    
B | 1,49    
B | 2,99    
B | 5,97    
B | 5,97    
B | 2,99    
B | 2,24    
B | 2,99    
C | 3,73    
C | 6,72    
C | 5,22    
C | 5,97    
D | 0,75    
D | 2,99    
E | 3,73    
E | 5,22    
E | 6,72    
E | 2,24    
E | 4,48    
E | 5,22    
E | 6,72    
F | 1,49    
F | 6,72    
F | 2,99    
F | 2,99
```

I would like to find the "Reference Price" that should be:

1. the closest match between Purchase Price (Table 1) and Market Prices (Table 2) given some unique GN (from Table 1) only if any of the Market Prices > Purchase Price.
2. Returns "Reference Price N/A" if the condition is not met (Market Prices > Purchase Price).

The outcome in this case should be as follows:

```
GN | Purchase Price | Reference Price (?)    
E | 2,36 | 3,73    
C |4,25 | 5,22    
F | 9,3 | Reference Price N/A    
A   | 1,2   | 2,99    
B | 7,63    | Reference Price N/A    
D   |5,47   | Reference Price N/A
```

Comment: So what formula(s) have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 excel then use MINIFS:

```
=MINIFS(H:H,H:H,">="&B2,G:G,A2)
```

This will return 0 not `Reference Price N/A` but you can put that in an IF to do that if you want:

```
=IF(MINIFS(H:H,H:H,">="&B2,G:G,A2),MINIFS(H:H,H:H,">="&B2,G:G,A2),"Reference Price N/A")
```

[image]

---

If you do not have Office 365 Excel then use AGGREGATE:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,7,$H$2:$H$26/(($H$2:$H$26>=B2)*($G$2:$G$26=A2)),1),"Reference Price N/A")
```

Note AGGREGATE is an array type formula and as such the referenced data should be limited to the data set, while the MAXIFS allows the use of full column references.

[image]